# xaml ScrollViewer, blurred border - Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Is it somehow possible to have somekind of a blurred border when scrolling? For better understanding I added a picture of what I want to acchieve.

The restriction that I have is, that underneath the `ScrollViewer` I have got a background Image. Thus, I cant just use a filled `Rectangle` with white to transparent gradient at the left side of the `ScrollViewer`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since WinRT dropped support for `OpacityMask` and I'm not sure if you'd want to set it with  an Alpha channel. With that said though, there's pretty much always a work around. So what if you just utilize the natural z-order instead and fake it? Something like this;

```
<!-- Grid as Container -->
<Grid>

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <!-- example backgrounds, like images, just for the concept example. -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Height="75" Width="300" Fill="Red" Margin="20,0"/>
            <Rectangle Height="75" Width="300" Fill="Red" Margin="20,0"/>
            <Rectangle Height="75" Width="300" Fill="Red" Margin="20,0"/>
            <Rectangle Height="75" Width="300" Fill="Red" Margin="20,0"/>
            <Rectangle Height="75" Width="300" Fill="Red" Margin="20,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <!-- An adhoc gradient overlay to just float over the ScrollViewer itself.
         Then using Margin to fit it to the shape of the Scrollviewer and still
         allow hit visibility to the scrollbar etc.  -->

    <Rectangle Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,20">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0.1,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.3"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>

</Grid>
```

Of course you'll probably want to tweak some values like the `Rectangle` `Margin` in the example to make it look exactly right with your own setup, but the concept should be there and is an option. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried, but as you can read in my question I do have set a background image of the page. Therefore I will get a vertical white stripe on my page with this solution.

Isn't there a method for getting a "blurr effect" without using the color white?

Comment: So just to clarify since apparently didn't understand. You have a ScrollViewer on top of an image you're using as a background, and in that scrollview you're showing images? Your little image appears to be a scrollviewer, with a picture in it? Perhaps you should screen shot what you have entirely for a better visual reference of what you're dealing with because it's apparently difficult to visualize based on the description and picture so far to understand your requirements.

Comment: I just uploaded a new draft of what I would like to acchieve. The image with the flower is a background image of the the main Grid. Then there is a ScrollViewer that contains images (to make it simple). In my real case I have got a GridView in the Scrollviewer which contains Images and TextBlocks of variable height.

Comment: Ah that's a bit more clear. Unfortunately there is no easy replacement for `OpacityMask` (not supported in WinRT) available for the effect you're shooting for. I suppose you could apply it via Alpha channel of the images themselves provided they're not dynamic. Or could look into `Direct2D` which is process intensive and not normally suggested. Beyond that, sorry mate but I don't have an answer for you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The images are dynamic. Well, as this isn' really crucial for my app I will note that it is just not possible or at least not with a big workaround.

Comment: Ya it really is unfortunate they're not supporting `OpacityMask` since that would fix this real quick with minimal effort. I imagine though they'll begin reconsidering adding its support considering the developer need for it. Best of luck!